# Laravel 5 - Class 'comment' not found

Tags: php, laravel

1. I created a new model with `php artisan make:model Comment` command
2. I created a new databse seeder named `CommentTableSeeder` with the following code:

   ```
   <?php
   ```

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CommentTableSeeder extends Seeder

```
{

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('comments')->delete();

    Comment::create(array(
    'author' => 'A name',
    'text' => 'Hello all nice website'
    ));

    Comment::create(array(
    'author' => 'name2',
    'text' => 'Hahahahha'
    ));

    Comment::create(array(
    'author' => 'Name 3,
    'text' => 'I destroy your car'
    ));
}
```

}

3. I ran the `php artisan db:seed` command and I get error:
   `Class 'Comment' not found`

Why?

Comment: Did you run the migration earlier ?

Comment: If you mean the database migration, yes

Comment: please share your complete seeder code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these lines:

```
use App\Comment;
```

Also, you can use this:

```
\App\Comment::
```

Instead of

```
Comment::
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you! I didn't know I need to mention the specific model.